# Plotting a 2D line over a figure 2D line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

I'm trying to plot a line over a figure line but couldn't plot it exactly on the axes. You can find the code here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1J12vWUIUr0dDIesMHBU9vYUkjnNKXOqT?usp=sharing

Here is the code for the 2D line which is then saved.

```
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot([10,45], [20,100], color="g")

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.axis([0, 144, 0, 144])
plt.figure(figsize = (2,2))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('testfig.png')
```

[image: ground truth]

Here is the code where I import the figure line and create a similar line with exact same coordinates and axes but couldn't figure it out. Green line is the imported one and the red one is the line to draw exactly over the imported one.

```
image = plt.imread('testfig.png')
#fig2 = plt.figure()
#fig2.set_size_inches(1,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot()
ax2.imshow(image, extent=[0, 144, 0, 144])

ax2.plot([10,45], [20,100], color="r")
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
ax2.set_axis_off()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.axis([0, 144, 0, 144])
plt.figure(figsize = (2,2))
print(image.shape)

plt.show()
```

[image: 2 lines]

Maybe it's because the exported line's shape comes out different from what I intended i.e 144x144. Is there a way to export exactly 144x144 without reshaping?

Comment: Could you turn on sharing for the link ? It is not accessible

Comment: Sorry about that. It's available for the public now.

Comment: If you want an image with just a line, matplotlib figures are not the best approach. Look up told to draw a line in a raw array.

Comment: A remark: `plt.figure(figsize = (2,2))` doesn't change the current figure size.  It creates a new empty figure with that size.   You might try `fig = plt.gcf()` and `fig.set_size_inches(2, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. Upon digging, I found that `plt.tight_layout()` has a default 1.08 padding: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html

The only thing I wanted was to pass `pad=0` as a parameter to `plt.tight_layout(pad=0)`. That's it.